# When is Python code between """ """ executed?

Tags: python, comments

I am very much a beginner in Python so this may be a stupid question.  But I learned that code between triple quotes, double or single, is comment code and not executed.  So I was very much surprised to find out that adding a certain comment to my code caused it to crash.  The following three lines show what I am talking about:

```
"""
\x
"""
```

They give the error:

```
runfile('C:/Python/backslash.py', wdir='C:/Python')
  File "C:/Python/backslash.py", line 10
    """
      ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 1-2: truncated \xXX escape
```

I would completely understand if `\x` caused this error in executable code, so no need to explain this error to me.  The question is why the code is executed and, more generally, other than backslashes do I need to worry about anything else between triple quotes?

I am running Python 3.5 via Anaconda3 on a Windows 7 computer.

Comment: docstrings are not comments, they are integral part of the code. A docstring declaration correspond to a real command assigning a string to the object's docstring `.__doc__` and so is evaluated like any other command.

Comment: That string is just a constant. It's like writing `5`. It doesn't do anything, but it's still executed.

Comment: Thanks for the answers above.  Now that my understanding of Python is a bit better, I will add that you can use triple quotes for commenting out code even if it contains string commands with \, as long as you use raw strings (r'''  commented out code block ''')